# Exceed Time Limit Leetcode

Tags: java

I was trying to use the following code to judge whether an integer is a Palindrome

```
public boolean isPalindrome(int num){
   if(num < 0) return  false; 
   int reversed = 0, remainder, original = num;
   while(num != 0) {
        remainder = num % 10; // reversed integer is stored in variable
        reversed = reversed * 10 + remainder; //multiply reversed by 10 then add the remainder so it 
gets stored at next decimal place.
        num  /= 10;  //the last digit is removed from num after division by 10.
    }
    // palindrome if original and reversed are equal
    return original == reversed;
}
```

The runtime complexity of this algorithm is $O(n)$ because you have to do num % 10 n times. However this exceeds the time limit.

Instead, the following algorithm works

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        // Special cases:
        // As discussed above, when x < 0, x is not a palindrome.
        // Also if the last digit of the number is 0, in order to be a palindrome,
        // the first digit of the number also needs to be 0.
        // Only 0 satisfy this property.
        if(x < 0 || (x % 10 == 0 && x != 0)) {
            return false;
        }

        int revertedNumber = 0;
        while(x > revertedNumber) {
            revertedNumber = revertedNumber * 10 + x % 10;
            x /= 10;
        }

        // When the length is an odd number, we can get rid of the middle digit by revertedNumber/10
        // For example when the input is 12321, at the end of the while loop we get x = 12, revertedNumber = 123,
       // since the middle digit doesn't matter in palidrome(it will always equal to itself), we can 
simply get rid of it.
       return x == revertedNumber || x == revertedNumber/10;
    }
}
```

Isn't its runtime complexity still O(n)?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: The outer loop is O(N), but you also need to account for the inner loop. The first loops `log10(num)` times, the second less than `log10(num)/2`.

Comment: But I only have one loop

Comment: As far as I can tell, both algorithms are O(n) where n is the number of digits, but yours has a bigger constant because your loop keeps going until the whole number is reversed, whereas the alternate solution only reverses half the number, so it does half as many divisions and modulos. Note the different `while` loop condition.

Comment: Leetcode only cares about time. While complexity influences time, it is not the complete picture. The second algorithm will go through a loop only half of the time, which may be significant. It also has a few special cases which may just make the difference.